# open_basedir error, but path is in open_basedir. PHP

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I am having a weird issue regarding an open_basedir error:

> file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(**/var/www/website-live/current/system/nitro/data/persistence.tpl**)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (**/var/www/website-live**:/var/www/website-git:/data/webserver_files:/var/www:/tmp)

I am using Capistrano to deploy the website, which works with a "current" symlink (as you see in the complete path above). The current symlink points to the latest release which is in **/var/www/website-live/releases**.

I am aware of the symlink restrictions to open_basedir, but that shouldn't be the issue now, right?

Answer (score 2):

Argh, I found the problem. Inside of the directory there was another symlink pointing to a place outside of the open_basedir. Fixed :)

Comment: This was useful for me: in my Debian installation, the Fileinfo magic file is a symlink